# The small things in life ("Sun ~Road")

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

### Try to make sense of the puzzle below and then replace the two question marks.

---

[image]

```
    |AP|ÉH|PE|ÉH|TD|ES|JV|WP|WH|RF|LB|
       |PD|MK|WB|HK|PD|AC|LD|MB|NB| 
       |IL|MP|MC|HL|??|PL|CG|CW|OR|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letters which replace the question marks are

> **AE**

Reasoning

> The letters given are, in the correct order, the initials of the people in this photograph
>  [image]
>  The absent initials belong to **Albert Einstein**

More Explanation

> This is a photo from the fifth Solvay conference in 1927 (notice how the first picture has the Roman numerals for "1", "9", "2" and "7" around the outside) which dealt with electrons and photons (the smaller things in life) and the development of quantum theory (see the equations on the blackboard from the first picture).

Title

> As pointed out by parz in the comments, "Sun ~Road" must be an approximation to "Sol vie" or "Solvay"

Comment: Sun ~Road must refer to SOLVAY (Sol + Vie, both translations), then.

Comment: @parz ah, yes, I left that bit out, sorry

Comment: I saw that and was like, “Hey, that’s convenient!”

Comment: THERE ARE NO COINCIDENCES

Comment: That was fast! Well done.